# Android Studio: Issues using spinner in one activity to change background color in another

Tags: java, android, null

I am very new to Android. The lab for my course on this requires that I be able to select a color from a spinner in activity A (PaletteActivity) and it launch activity B (CanvasActivity) with that color as the background.

However, the app crashes saying I attempted to invoke the virtual method `private void setBgColor(String selectedColor)` on a null object reference. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Here is the code for PaletteActivity:

```
package com.example.codyhunsberger.cis_3515_lab_3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class PaletteActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_palette);
    final Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CanvasActivity.class);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String[] strings = {"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Cyan","Gray","Magenta"};

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(PaletteActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            strings);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class));
            String strName = null;
            String color = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            i.putExtra(color, strName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


}

}
```

And CanvasActivity:

```
package com.example.codyhunsberger.cis_3515_lab_3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CanvasActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_canvas);

        String color = "";

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            color = "White";
        }
        else {
            extras.getString(color);
        }

        setBgColor(color);
    }

    private void setBgColor(String selectedColor){
        RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

        switch (selectedColor) {
            case "Red":
                myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case "Green":
                myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case "Blue":
                myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case "Cyan":
                myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                break;
            case "White":
                myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;
            case "Gray":
                myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                break;
            case "Magenta":
                myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                break;
        }

        if (selectedColor.equals("White")) {
            Toast.makeText(CanvasActivity.this, "Bundle extras is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

If the XML files would help I can add those too, but I'm fairly certain they're not related. Thanks for looking!

*Update: stack trace for second error issue:*

```
09-24 14:53:31.600 19931-19931/com.example.codyhunsberger.cis_3515_lab_3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                           Process: com.example.codyhunsberger.cis_3515_lab_3, PID: 19931
                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.codyhunsberger.cis_3515_lab_3/com.example.codyhunsberger.cis_3515_lab_3.CanvasActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
                                                                                               at com.example.codyhunsberger.cis_3515_lab_3.CanvasActivity.setBgColor(CanvasActivity.java:31)
                                                                                               at com.example.codyhunsberger.cis_3515_lab_3.CanvasActivity.onCreate(CanvasActivity.java:25)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the right intent for starting the activity. Change your code as following:

```
 // startActivity(new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class));
 // String strName = null;
 String color = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
 i.putExtra("color", color);
 startActivity(i);
```

Also, in your `CanvasActivity`, you need to save the read value:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
    color = "White";
} 
else { 
    color = extras.getString("color");
}
```

**EDIT:** Your key for the values was used incorrectly above. Made the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This definitely got me closer to a working product, but now there is an even more vague error message of the same type but in reference to the method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()'

Comment: @user3491551 Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @hunsbct Alright, you made the required changes in the second activity too, right? Also, log the value of the `color` right before calling `setBgColor(color);`

Comment: I made the changes to both, and logged the value just before the method call.

Comment: I believe so, I saw your edit to the original reply and updated everything. It's now back to saying void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(int) is invoked on a null object reference.

Comment: @hunsbct that is a completely different issue. Make sure that `myLayout` is within layout file `activity_canvas.xml`. If that doesn't fix the issue open another question.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by going back to my activity XMLs and adding proper IDs. They were mismatched for Canvas Activity.

It still launches to the wrong activity by default, but this is a separate issue.